# Mollweide's formula : A proof

Tags: trigonometry

I encountered Mollweide's formula and I search the net for the proof.. I got this link [Link](https://planetmath.org/ProofOfMollweidesEquations) . I studied the proof and it requires a lot of trigonometric identities. Can we have another means in proving this identity? A better approach? thanks a lot in advance..:)

By the way the Mollweide's formula is:

Given any triangle with $a,\ b,\ c,  \ \alpha ,\ \beta, \ \gamma $.$$\frac{a+b}{c}= \frac{\cos (\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2})}{\sin (\frac{\gamma}{2})}$$  and
$$\frac{a-b}{c}= \frac{\sin (\frac{\alpha - \beta}{2})}{\cos(\frac{\gamma}{2})}$$

Comment: For those like me who did not know about them, here is a link to [Mollweide's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide's_formula).

Comment: @lhf, thanks for the link ..:).. I forgot to put the formula, So, I edited it. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[image: Mollweide's formula: proof without words]

Screenshot from http://cartography.tuwien.ac.at/content07/index.php?download=Lapaine_Mollweide_draft_paper.pdf

Proof attributed to H. Arthur De Kleine, "Proof Without Words: Mollweide's Equation", *Mathematics Magazine*, volume 61, number 5, page 281, December, 1988.